# Add variables to python SQL string

Tags: python, oracle

I have searched and tried every possible way ( I believe) to be able to pass parameters to my SQL string which is inside of my Pyhton code. I am getting as errors either:
1. cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number; or,
2. typeerror: 'str' object is not callable

Below is a simple version of what I am trying to do. In the end, I have a list of string names from a list that I want to be looped using 'for', but I figure, lets get this simple version working first.

I have been able to get this to work without parameter substitution.

Any ideas?

```
X = 'XX_Delete'
connection = cx_Oracle.connect('p123/p132.xyz@oratfc01')
cursor = connection.cursor()
#cursor.execute('Create TABLE %s as select * from tsapw_period where diskey = 200', X)
#cursor.execute('Create TABLE %s as select * from tsapw_period where diskey = 200', (X))
#cursor.execute('Create TABLE %s as select * from tsapw_period where diskey = 200', str(X))
#cursor.execute('Create TABLE :s as select * from tsapw_period where diskey = 200', (X))
#cursor.execute('Create TABLE :s as select * from tsapw_period where diskey = 200' %(X))
sql = "Create TABLE :s as select * from tsapw_period where diskey = 200"
param = (X)
cursor.execute(sql, param)
```

Comment: Have you tried `cursor.execute('...%s...' % X)`? But this should be just used as a quick test.

Comment: got error: 
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01722: invalid number

Comment: May there is no possibility to bind a table name to a statement. Binding table names by format strings you should handle with care.

Answer (score 0):

Try (X,) i.e. with a comma between X and the closing parenthesis which basically ensures that you're passing in a tuple with one element as the second parameter. For two ore more elements in the tuple, you don't need the trailing comma. Hope this helps.

Comment: cursor.execute('Create TABLE %s as select * from tsapw_period where diskey = 200', (X,)) Got error: cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number

Answer (score 0):

The best way to add variables into SQL statements is to use prepared statements like you try to do. With this statements, it's hard injecting bad code by the user.

There are different methods to [bind Variable Patterns](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/prez-python-queries-101587.html).

For your example, that should be:

`cursor.execute('Create TABLE :tab as (select * from tsapw_period where diskey = 200)', tab='foo')`

or

`cursor.execute('Create TABLE :0 as (select * from tsapw_period where diskey = 200)', ('foo',))`

Comment: cursor.execute('Create TABLE :tab as select * from tsapw_period where diskey = 200', tab= X) Got error: cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number

Comment: @DavidCampbell Try to get the resulting SQL string and execute it e.g. with sqlplus to avoid problems with the query itself.

Comment: @DavidCampbell I have added some parentheses around the `select`. Checkout the [documentation](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/tables/create_table2.php).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, it did not like that I was passing parameters in that way. This worked:

```
cursor.execute('Create TABLE {} as select * from tsapw_period where diskey = 200'.format(X))
```

Comment: Inserting a variable is not the best solution. Have you tried my latest edit with parentheses?

Comment: May there is no possibility to bind a table name to a prepared statement. Binding table names by format strings you should handle with care.